I've felt relief of the headache [in] ten minutes after I've put on the ice?

February 5th.—The burning pain at the top of the head and the pain in the face were less severe; the pain in the arm and the pain and burning in the roof of the mouth and throat were again lessened, and she had less throbbing than before. I said to her, —"The ice did not make your feet cold, did it?" "No, sir," she answered, "it did not; indeed they are rather warmer than they were—my hands too; and my appetite has been very good this last week. I have seemed better altogether. I've felt relief of the headache in ten minutes after I've put on the ice." I advised her to continue its use during sixty minutes twice a day, as last ordered, but also to apply an Ice-bag across the occiput, from ear to ear, each morning an hour before the attack came on.

Cases of Neuralgia and of Other Diseases of the Nervous System by John Chapman
This sentence made me think about something. I know that we can't use the Present Perfect with specific time references (last week, this morning, several minutes ago, etc.) but this is different. She says, among the other things, that she's felt relief of the headache in ten minutes after she's put on the ice, probably several times during the last week.
So, my question is: would it be correct to say, for example: "During the last week, I've felt relief of the headache, usually ten minutes after I've put on the ice."?
To me it sounds correct but how does it sound to you?
Source: Cases of Neuralgia and of Other Diseases of the Nervous System by John Chapman

Considering that it is reported speech using 'ser' for 'sir', and 'wormer' for 'warmer' it's moot whether she should have said 'within' instead of 'in'. The text tries to render the vernacular.

@WeatherVane Is this centence correct: "During the last week, I've felt relief of the headache, usually ten minutes after I've put on the ice."? It sounds good to me.

I think I'd prefer relief from the headache but Chapman's book was published in 1873.

I don't buy that ...probably several times during the last week interpretation. To me, the cited text strongly implies that relief after only 10 minutes was a remarkable outcome that only happened once (on a "cherry-picked" occasion). BTW - there are a lot of transcription errors in the cited ext. What happened to cut&paste?

@WeatherVane: Ser isn't "eye dialect" - it's mistranscription by an OP failing to use cut&paste for a freely-available text. Same with it's for its, wormer for warmer, and probably several more.

@FumbleFingers perhaps. Those errors are in the reported speech, but 'an Ice-beg' is not.

@FumbleFingers I've found this excerpt on the Google Books and there is no option for cut/copy & past, so I've just written it down. All the mistakes are exactly the same in the original text. I didn't want to correct them because that wouldn't be the same than. Nevertheless,  what do you think about my sentence: "During the last week, I've felt relief of the headache, usually ten minutes after I've put on the ice."? Is it correct?

@FumbleFingers It's for its was my mistake!

Yes, that's what I meant. The containing text is so old it's never been electronically typeset. But I just searched Google Books for "week. I have seemed better altogether", which gives 2-3 sentences within the GB "thumbnail view" results. I never type anything I can cut&paste! Whatever - text that old, from such a context, is hardly relevant to learning current English.

MickeyQ There were rather more than that. Thanks @FumbleFingers for the link, I've corrected what I found.

Your proposed edit is a perfectly natural sentence. But if your goal is to retain the meaning of the original text, I would not add usually.
As the comments note, the original text is old, with language that tries to represent dialectical speech, or has printing errors, or both. The result is that its meaning is ambiguous. I've felt relief could mean anything from "I felt relief once", to "I've felt relief sometimes", to "I felt relief every time" I applied the ice. Similarly in ten minutes could mean "at the ten minute mark** or "within a ten minute period".
So what's wrong with usually? Nothing grammatically, but what it does is resolve the ambiguity. In effect you are stating which of those options you agree with. And other people may have different views.

I just wanted to determine whether I can use the Present Perfect with the specific time references in a certain situations. That's why I provided a context where I thought it woud reflect my point. I made a mistake! That wasn't a good idea. I should've just written my own sentence and asked for your explanation, which I'm gonna do in my next quotation. Anyway, thank you all for your comments and answers!

If it's helpful, think about the tenses I used: (1) I felt relief once (I chose the simple past because it was a single event). (2) I've felt relief sometimes (I chose the perfect to cover a range of events over a period of time). (3) I felt relief every time... (I chose the simple past because every made it feel like the tense was referring to each event individually, one at a time). As always, other options are possible, but that's how I thought of it.
